# Python program to simulate the trajectory of a cannonball

Tags: python

I am new into programming. Here, I am trying to simulate the motion of a cannonball until it hits the ground using python programming. I have used both analytical and numerical(Euler method) to plot its trajectory. But, I am not sure if my output is correct for both methods, especially for the analytical solution. For analytical solution, is there any way to show that for t=0, x=1m which is true. 
Please look at the code below, and point out my mistakes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
v=0.0      #Initial 0 velocity
h=0.01     #dt
x=1        #Canonball is at a distance of 1m from the ground initially     
t=0.0
m=2.0
g=9.81 

ta,xa,xb=[],[],[]   #xa for numerical and xb for analytical solution

while x>=0.0:
    ta.append(t)
    xa.append(x)
    xb.append(-0.5*g*t**2.0)  #Analytical solution
    F=-m*g                       #Numerical solution
    v=v+(F/m)*h
    x=x+v*h
    t=t+h

plt.figure()
plt.plot(ta,xa)
plt.plot(ta,xb,'ro-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: At `t=0`, `-0.5*g*t**2.0` is not equal to 1.

Comment: Yes chris, that's where the problem lies for analytical solution. I don't think that my coding for numerical solution is incorrect.

Comment: Why don't you have the constant shift in there, `-0.5*g*t**2.0+1`?

Comment: Oh great, Thank you Chris, you're a life saver. Do you think that my code need any further improvements, being a novice in this field of programming.

Comment: I don't see another obvious mistake, but I'd have to plot it to really know for sure. But in almost every case, you'll want to use some kind of differential equation solver software instead of hardcoding an Euler method. It will be much more efficient, and much easier to control the accuracy.

Comment: Thanks. I plotted both the solutions. It looks good to me. Actually, I am new to programming, so want to do basic stuffs before embarking into scipy and stuffs.